# Spring Security antMachers

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.2.0.RELEASE.
I want to redirect user to another URL if he is not permitted to see the page, how can I  do this?

```
.antMatchers("/cabinet/control/members/*").hasRole("OWNER").redirectTo(..)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a access denied handler/page, see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#access-denied-handler):

> If an `AccessDeniedException` is thrown and a user has already been authenticated, then this means that an operation has been attempted for which they don’t have enough permissions. In this case, `ExceptionTranslationFilter` will invoke a second strategy, the `AccessDeniedHandler`. By default, an `AccessDeniedHandlerImpl` is used, which just sends a 403 (Forbidden) response to the client. Alternatively you can configure an instance explicitly (as in the above example) and set an error page URL which it will forwards the request to [[13](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_footnote_13)]. This can be a simple "access denied" page, such as a JSP, or it could be a more complex handler such as an MVC controller. And of course, you can implement the interface yourself and use your own implementation.

Example:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/cabinet/control/members/*").hasRole("OWNER")
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access_denied.jsp")
            .and()
        .formLogin();
}
```